# Track file again after deletion

Tags: git

I accidently deleted my wordpress themes folder. So i did `git checkout -- .` to revert my changes. Now it says that I need to track the folder again. So do I need to commit my whole theme folder to my upstream again?

Comment: Did you `git rm` your themes folder? Or did you just `rm` your folder?

Comment: I did just `rm`

Answer (score 0):

when you deleted accidentally. if it is already tracked before you can do this

```
git checkout path/to/folder-you-want-to-restore
```

If you think your local is messed up and need to be in sync with upstream do this

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/branch
```

this will bring back all deleted files/folders if they present in remote.

Comment: This still leaves my themes folder untracked on local.

Comment: When you say untracked is it not added to git? What is the exact git status? Before you delete did you make any changes to files inside that folder which needs to be committed or is it sync with the origin